# How to remove time stamp from datetime value in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How can I remove the timestamp from following DateTime column?
11/10/2018 11:27:00 a.m.

SQL ISDATE() function returns false for above format. The above date format is coming from an external source (eg. CSV).

Comment: The tag description for [tag:sql] says "Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. " You've included none of those things.

Comment: The easiest way to handle issues around dates and times is generally also the hardest..  Can you get the date/time format in your source .csv file changed to ISO 8601 format?  If not, you're going to have to parse your source data and rewrite the datetime values into a 'better' format.

Comment: @user5151179 I am not getting any format in the source file.

Comment: do a `CONVERT( DATE , yourcol )`

Comment: @Shereen - You said in your question "The above date format is coming from an external source", I was trying to say that the easiest way forward would be to request that the date/time data in the external data be presented in ISO 8601 format.  Talk to whoever is giving you the data, ask them if they can format the dates accordingly.  If the date/time is formatted according to the ISO standard, your life will be easier.  Failing that, you will a technical solution (parse/reassemble).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Format()` function after you did your `IsDate()` check. For example:

```
Format(YourDateTimeColumn, "dd.MM.yyyy") 'Displays 29.10.2018
Format(YourDateTimeColumn, "MM/dd/yyyy") 'Displays 10/29/2018
```